# Best way to check if Twilio authentication is successful with JS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

What is the best way to check if Twilio auht_token, account_sid are correct and sms can be sent, number checked? Some call which doesn't cost extra credits?

E.g. I see https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records on RESTfull documentation but can't find how to get the same thing with JS SDK. Can't see dedicated endpoint for config checking so looking for anything else.

Environment: NodeJS 8.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Most API calls to the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api) don't cost, particularly those where you retrieve a resource or list resources. Since you mentioned SMS you could, for example, [list your latest messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message?code-sample=code-list-all-messages&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x) like this:

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.list({ limit: 10 })
  .then(function(messages) {
    console.log("Everything is good!");
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Something went wrong: ", err)
  })
```

Take a look through the API reference and pick one that takes your fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Using JS SDK might be insecure here. Because of that I think they didn't include a method in the JS API which may present the user the account_sid and the auth_token, which may be exploited. I assume you can use a server bridge between your client JS and Twilio API. Like this:

1. Client makes a JS AJAX request to http://my.domain.tld/checkstatus
2. Server connects to the Twilio API with C#, PHP, NodeJS or whatever tech it uses
3. Twilio returns that the credentials and tokens are still valid or expired
4. Server prepares the client response as true/false or 0/1
5. Client reads the status and continues or redirects somewhere else.

---

**Edit** There's a GET method here which you can also use with JS AJAX call:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records#list-get

which is requested by this format:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Usage/Records/{Subresource}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm running JS at server side so it's OK. Addded NodeJs tag to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry then, I got it wrong as you might be using this on client side.